# Hubot Scripts integrating with Asana

Tags: api, node.js, coffeescript, asana, hubot

I am working on making my first Hubot script which would add a quick task to Asana.
I'm not looking at doing anything too crazy, or at least didn't think I was.

Currently I have

```
url  = 'https://app.asana.com/api/1.0'

WORKSPACE = "1111111111111"
user = "xxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
pass = ""

module.exports = (robot) ->
  robot.respond /task (.*)/i, (msg) ->
    params = {name: "#{msg.match[1]}", workspace: "#{WORKSPACE}"}
    stringParams = JSON.stringify params
    auth = 'Basic ' + new Buffer("#{user}:#{pass}").toString('base64')
    msg.http("#{url}/tasks")
      .headers("Authorization": auth, "Content-Length": stringParams.length, "Accept": "application/json")
      .query(params)
      .post() (err, res, body) ->
        console.log(err)
        console.log(res)
        console.log(body)
        msg.send body
```

All I really want it to do is output that it's posting to the workspace. I know there is more to the Asana API to make it all work properly, but watching my log's tail, nothing is outputting, nothing is logging to console, nothing is happening.

If I do a console.log under the params, it will output the JSON and it's correct, but it seems like the post is never happening.

Any direction would be great!

Thanks.

**EDIT**

After some more tweaking, following Dan was a step in the right direction, dropping .query() and putting the string in .post() the output is finally correct.

```
module.exports = (robot) ->
  robot.respond /task (.*)/i, (msg) ->
    params = {data:{name: "#{msg.match[1]}", workspace: "#{WORKSPACE}"}}
    stringParams = JSON.stringify params
    auth = 'Basic ' + new Buffer("#{user}:#{pass}").toString('base64')
    msg.http("#{url}/tasks")
      .headers("Authorization": auth, "Content-Length": stringParams.length, "Accept": "application/json")
      .post(stringParams) (err, res, body) ->
        console.log(err)
        console.log(res)
        console.log(body)
        msg.send body
```

Comment: Don't forget it has to be inside a `data` parameter of the top-level object. `{data:{parameters:values}}`

Comment: Thanks @DanRedux, I gave that a shot, but didn't change anything. :-/

Comment: After a bit for tweaking, it finally worked out. Thanks for the pointer!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Submitting an answer to the question so stackoverflow won't show it as unanswered.

Copying from EDIT in OP.

dropping .query() and putting the string in .post() the output is finally correct.

```
module.exports = (robot) ->
  robot.respond /task (.*)/i, (msg) ->
    params = {data:{name: "#{msg.match[1]}", workspace: "#{WORKSPACE}"}}
    stringParams = JSON.stringify params
    auth = 'Basic ' + new Buffer("#{user}:#{pass}").toString('base64')
    msg.http("#{url}/tasks")
      .headers("Authorization": auth, "Content-Length": stringParams.length, "Accept": "application/json")
      .post(stringParams) (err, res, body) ->
        console.log(err)
        console.log(res)
        console.log(body)
        msg.send body
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the http client in Hubot expects an object for `query()`, not a string. Try passing the object directly in instead of calling `JSON.stringify`.